# Detect when gutenberg editor title is available in Dom after editor load

Tags: filters, hooks, block-editor

I have some code I run inside the `PrePublishCheckList` block

```
const title =
        typeof coreEditorPostEditsTitle !== "undefined"
            ? coreEditorPostEditsTitle
            : select("core/editor").getCurrentPost().title;

    const [event, setEvent] = useState(2019);
    // todo:: Find a better way to hook after gutenberg loaded and .editor-post-title__input" is available in dom
    setTimeout(() => {
        const editorTitleElement = document.querySelector(
            ".editor-post-title__input"
        );

        if(
            typeof select("core/editor").loadedInit === "undefined" &&
            !title.length
        ) {
            pickDropdownNotice(title);
            // Open right sidebar
            dispatch("core/edit-post").openPublishSidebar();
            // Set default event loadFromApi(event, setEvent);

            select("core/editor").loadedInit = true;
        }

        if(title.length) {
            showEditorTitle(editorTitleElement);
        } else {
            hideEditorTitle(editorTitleElement);
        }
    }, 100);

const showEditorTitle = editorTitleElement => {
    editorTitleElement.style.display = "block";
    editorTitleElement.readOnly = true;
    editorTitleElement.style.background = "#eee";
    editorTitleElement.style.color = "#32373c";
};

const hideEditorTitle = editorTitleElement => {
    editorTitleElement.style.display = "none";
};
```

The code goal is to hide the title until event is selected from a dropdown in the `PrePublishCheckList` that updates the title of the post and saves a draft.

The code works fine, the only issue is I can find a build in hook to find out when the `".editor-post-title__input"` element is available in dom. I know I can set a timeout that will check again and again until the element is visible in dom, but setTimeout feels like a hack.

Which other way can replace the setTimeout so the code inside the setTimeout will run only after the `.editor-post-title__input"` is in ready in Dom?

The error I get when I remove the setTimeout is in hideEditorTitle 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` on `editorTitleElement.style.display = "none";` inside hideEditorTitle()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding inline CSS on an element with `style=".."` is bad practice, people say to use a CSS rule in a stylesheet instead, via a HTML class. So it doesn't make much sense to start styling things manually via javascript like that.

Instead, wouldn't it make more sense to add a stylesheet that hides the title, then shows it when a CSS class is added to the main editor tag? Then add the class when your event is selected from the dropdown?

Additionally, you shouldn't be doing this:

```js
select("core/editor").loadedInit = true;
```

If you want to store data, there's the WP Data API for that, and other alternatives.

Also, don't use `setTimeout`, use the `window._wpLoadBlockEditor` promise to queue stuff up to run after the editor has been initialised instead, e.g.

```js
window._wpLoadBlockEditor.then( function() {
    console.log( 'hooray!' );
});
```

If you do this though, make sure you correctly declare your scripts dependencies! If you don't declare them WordPress won't print out the script tags in the correct order and it might load *before* the `_wpLoadBlockEditor` variable has been set up.

Comment: Great suggestion, the hook worked!
Can you please refer me to docs/examples about "WP Data API for that, and other alternatives"? I was looking into this but wasn't sure was is the correct approach.  Basically I want to show a notice only once to choose item from the dropdown to create post this is why is used   select("core/editor").loadedInit = true

Comment: The gutenberg gh repo has documentation in the data package, and there's the official docs/official handbook at `developer.wordpress.org`. You shouldn't take random APIs and just attach variables to them, I'd also be wary of making these kinds of changes to the editor UI if it can't be done using React components and a dedicated API, chances are it will break either with the html class changing or because of future changes to the editor

Comment: Seems like there is no build in way to set the title to be readonly. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329457/set-post-title-to-read-only-and-disable-permalink-slug-editor-in-gutenberg

Comment: If you know about a approach to do this in a build way I would like to hear. I looked at the components files, there do seem to accept any args for attr

Comment: Ah you never mentioned that you were wanting a read only title, you should have asked about that. It appears your question was an X Y question

Comment: Tried the `window._wpLoadBlockEditor` code and got an error unfortunately: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

Comment: if you aren't declaring any dependencies for your script then WP might load it _before_ those variables are ready to be used. Likewise the code will trigger that error if used on a page that isn't a block editor

Comment: Enqueuing via the `enqueue_block_editor_assets` hook seems to fix deps. This code works (but needs to be built via wp-scripts):

`import domReady from '@wordpress/dom-ready'

domReady( () => {
 if ( window._wpLoadBlockEditor ) {
  window._wpLoadBlockEditor.then( function() {
   console.log('editor seems ready');
  } )
 }
} )`

However the editor doesn't seem 100% ready, retriving the list of added blocks with `wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlockOrder();` returns an empty array.

Comment: if you declare dependencies that should help but you should definitely be using that hook to enqueue all block related things. `domReady` might help workaround those issues if you aren't but this is very much order dependent. If you register a block or plugin and do the work from their callbacks that also sidesteps this issue entirely. It's also possible to have a block editor that has no title blocks etc, especially if the editor is in site editing/template editing mode, or editing a sub-post/template/pattern. For you I'd suggest registering a plugin. There may be a JS hook but I can't see it